# Row in Android CustomAdapter showing not in full width

Tags: android, listview, row, adapter

I have the following problem:
I created a row.xml file for using in my CustomAdapter. This row will be part of ListView.
This is a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Slashdot"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The row shows not in full available width in case TextView messageText is few characters that don't fill the entire row(shorter than the entire row). It creates several problems for me: problem in appearance, problem when I try to select some row, in case a messageText is only a few characters long, I have to select exactly the available characters instead of just "clicking" on entire row.

Thanks in advance

Update:
The rows look something like this:

---

User1 01:01:01
Some Text1

---

User2 01:01:01
Some Text2

---

Instead of:

---

User1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 01:01:01
Some Text1

---

User2-----------------------------------------------------------------------------01:01:01
Some Text2

---

In first case if I want to select some row I need to "click" on "Some Text" exactly.
I want to be able to select some row "click" by clicking anywhere on that row

Comment: How are you setting the click listener for your listview?

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot, there's nothing obvious wrong with the XML.

Comment: registerForContextMenu(myListView;

Comment: I don't have enough "reputation" to post an images..

Answer (score 0):

Assign the width to your TextView's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUser"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slashdot"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried, but I didn't solve the issue. In addition, the inner layout must be horizontal because I want the "textUser" and "time" to be in the same row.

Comment: I can do it , but I want to set it to the maximum available width depending on device, not fixed size

Comment: ya,for that you can add layout-small,layout-large, layout-xlarge folders , & modify the width accordingly in it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. There is no more generic solution available?

Comment: There could be, but generally I use this method

Comment: try using 
               `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` in textvew